# Elasticsearch query always returns

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying a small test index.

http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search

```
{
   "query": { 
     "match": { 
        "text_index": "Some test text."
     }
   }
}
```

Every query, regardless of  what it is, returns the full set.

Comment: can you please add sample document and sample query text you are trying to execute ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you actually have a "field" in your index called "test_index". By default elasticsearch will give it a "text" mapping, as well as a "keyword" mapping.

Assuming that is the case,lets take a look at how elasticsearch has tokenized the text you are searching with:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "some test text."
}
```

And the result:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "some",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "text",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 14,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This tells you what ES sees when it attempts to search. This is also the same way in which ES splits the text inside your documents.

So given the above assumptions:

1. ALL your documents have one of the three searched terms.
2. Your field is configured with some strange analyzer, that is probably including whitespace as a search term and hence returning every single document.
3. You have a syntactical error in your search request, which may actually be ignoring the "query" clause entirely and simply returning the result of doing:

```
http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search
```

without any query, and the result of that is ALWAYS every single document in the index.

I hope this helps you debug this very strange behaviour.

Bye.

Comment: Thank you. I think you're probably right on there being some sort of minor error meaning it's defaulting to showing all.

Comment: Pls do mark my answer as correct if that is the case! Thanks and all the very best on your journey into Elasticsearch!